# Javascript Moment.js add to date (twice a month)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using Moment.js and I need to create a for loop that adds a specific number of days to a date variable called `theDate`, so the `'theDate'` keeps advancing in a semi-monthly order (twice a month).

This example works for adding a single day (one by one) to dueDate

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    moment(theDate).add(i, 'day').add(1,'day');
    console.log(dueDate);
}
```

And if the `'theDate'` is set to `18.Jan.2017`, then above will print the following:

```
1/18/17
1/19/17
1/20/17
1/21/17
1/22/17
```

...

I need to figure out how to add the number of days (or weeks, etc.) so the result is adding days in a semi-monthly (twice a month) order. Meaning, if my starting date is set `18.Jan.2017`, the result should look like this for the entire year `2017`:

```
1/18/17
2/01/17
2/18/17
3/04/17
3/18/17
4/01/17
4/18/17
5/02/17
5/18/17
6/01/17
6/18/17
7/02/17
7/18/17
8/01/17
8/18/17
9/01/17
9/18/17
10/02/17
10/18/17
11/01/17
11/18/17
12/02/17
12/18/17
```

Please note that I am not looking for a 1 and 15th type of solution as we usually see with paycheques. I need twice a month payments based on a starting date, which can be anything user decides to set it to.

Comment: on average, a month as just over 30 days, so adding 15 days to the last date should get you the closest to twice a month.

Comment: Nope, that won't work either, because if the theDate is set to 1.January, than your idea would result in 3 payments... #1 - Jan 1st, #2 - January 15th, #3 - January 30th... And that's not a definition of semi-monthly (twice a month)

Comment: then, you don't have a choice, you need to choose two dates arbitrarily with the one chosen by the user. e.g. if the user chooses the 23th day, you could add 15, wrapping if over 30 (or 28 to be sure) and setting the second date to be the 10th day of each month.

Comment: Why are you alternating between the 1st and the 2nd for each month?  What would expect for other months if they picked the 31st of a month?  What is the actual objective you are maximizing for?  Please define your algorithm in pseudocode or human terms so we know what you actually want.

Comment: The difference between your example dates vary, sometimes they are 14 days apart, sometimes 18 days apart.  Sometimes days fall on a Wed, other times they fall on a Saturday.  Can you clarify what you are looking to calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering about this, until I found myself the answer that worked the best for me:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
   if (i % 2 === 1) {
     finalDate = moment(theDate).add((1/2)*i, 'month');
   } else {
     finalDate = moment(theDate).add((1/2)*i, 'month').subtract(2,'weeks');
   }
  console.log(finalDate);
}
```

So, e.g. if the theDate is set to January 18th 2017, it'll print:

```
January 18th 2017
February 3rd 2017
February 18th 2017
March 3rd 2017
March 18th 2017
April 3rd 2017
April 18th 2017
May 3rd 2017
May 18th 2017
June 3rd 2017
June 18th 2017
July 3rd 2017
July 18th 2017
August 3rd 2017
August 18th 2017
September 3rd 2017
September 18th 2017
October 3rd 2017
October 18th 2017
November 3rd 2017
November 18th 2017
December 3rd 2017
December 18th 2017
```

Comment: This code doesn't work out of the box, it outputs the moment object, and not a formatted date, it also outputs the second payment date first. I tweaked it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Based on your answer, I tweaked the code to optimize, make it more clear and make it work out of the box.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    var finalDate = moment([2017, 0, 31]).add(Math.ceil(0.5 * i), 'month');
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        finalDate.subtract(2, 'weeks');
    }
    console.log(finalDate.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
}
```

This outputs exactly:

```
2017/01/31
2017/02/14
2017/02/28
2017/03/17
2017/03/31
2017/04/16
2017/04/30
2017/05/17
2017/05/31
2017/06/16
2017/06/30
2017/07/17
2017/07/31
2017/08/17
2017/08/31
2017/09/16
2017/09/30
2017/10/17
2017/10/31
2017/11/16
2017/11/30
2017/12/17
2017/12/31
2018/01/17
```

Please note that **adding half a month with moment adds a whole month**. To make this behavior more obvious, I'm explicitly rounding up.

#### Original answer based on assumptions

If you want fixed semi-monthly to the eyes of a user, you could take the day the user has chosen and, based on it, set a second date yourself.

If the user chooses the 23th day, add 15, wrapping if over 28 (to be sure) and setting the second date to be the 10th day of each month.

Since each month it is two fixed dates, you don't need to add days anymore. You just need to add a month. It's as simple as this:

```js
var userChosenDate = 23,
    // if the user chose 28 and higher, just use 28 as a starting point.
    yourChosenPaymentDate = (Math.min(userChosenDate, 28) + 15) % 28,
    firstPayment = Math.min(userChosenDate, yourChosenPaymentDate),
    secondPayment = Math.max(userChosenDate, yourChosenPaymentDate);

for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  console.log(i + "/" + firstPayment + "/2017");
  console.log(i + "/" + secondPayment + "/2017");
}
```

With momentJs:

```
var userChosenDate = 23,
    yourChosenPaymentDate = (Math.min(userChosenDate, 28) + 15) % 28,
    firstPayment = moment(Math.min(userChosenDate, yourChosenPaymentDate) + "/1/2017", "D/M/YYYY"),
    secondPayment = moment(firstPayment)
                      .date(Math.max(userChosenDate, yourChosenPaymentDate)),
    format = "MM/DD/YYYY";


console.log(firstPayment.format(format));
console.log(secondPayment.format(format));
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    console.log(firstPayment.add(1, 'month').format(format));
    console.log(secondPayment.add(1, 'month').format(format));
}
```

Comment: thank, but I think I found even a better way, please see the answer I just posted... it's working flawlessly and using less code...

Answer (score -1):

Try my [clock.js](https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js) script.

```js
var twoWeeks = clock.unit.weeks * 2;
var twoWeeksFromToday = clock.now + twoWeeks;

console.log(clock.what.weekday(twoWeeksFromToday) + ' ' + clock.what.month(twoWeeksFromToday) + ' ' + clock.what.day(twoWeeksFromToday));
```

```html
<script src="https://rack.pub/clock.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This won't work, it's adding 2 weeks... that's not what I am after... I require semi-monthly, not bi-weekly.

Comment: Plus I need it working using moments.js. But thanks for trying.